# Jackson annotation "JsonValue" doesn't work

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want the following enum to be serialized/deserialized using the apiValue (SUN, MON, ...) instead of the enum value (SUNDAY, MONDAY, ....). I use the @JsonValue annotation but it doesn't work (i.e. it uses the enum value). Any idea how to fix this issue ?

```
import java.util.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

public enum ApiNotificationScheduleDayInWeek {
        SUNDAY("SUN", 1), 
        MONDAY("MON", 2), 
        TUESDAY("TUE", 3), 
        WEDNESDAY("WED", 4), 
        THURSDAY("THU", 5), 
        FRIDAY("FRI", 6), 
        SATURDAY("SAT", 7), 
        WEEKDAY("WEEKDAY", 8),
        WEEKEND("WEEKEND", 9);
    private String apiValue;
    private Integer intValue;

    @JsonValue
    public String getApiValue() {
        return apiValue;
    }

    private ApiNotificationScheduleDayInWeek(String apiValue, Integer intValue) {
        this.apiValue = apiValue;
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the serialization code. An [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the serialization part correctly, so something else is wrong. Since you're using Jackson2 annotations, verify you're using Jackson2 for serialization (not Jackson1 or any other library). Also do the general sanity checks, such as checking whether you've compiled your classes, deployed your application, etc.

As for deserialization, you also need to tell Jackson how to get the enum instance from your API value. For this, you can annotate a static lookup method with `@JsonCreator`. Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;

@JsonCreator
public static ApiNotificationScheduleDayInWeek fromApiValue(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for (ApiNotificationScheduleDayInWeek day : ApiNotificationScheduleDayInWeek.values()) {
        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(day.getApiValue())) {
            return day;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid API value: " + value);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to have a method annotated as JsonCreator in order to make JsonValue work ?

Comment: No, `@JsonCreator` is for deserialization. Serialization should work with just `@JsonValue`. We use both in our projects, and it works as expected.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh if you're still having trouble with this, please post additional details, as was mentioned in another comment: how you serialize values, including any configuration of ObjectMapper and such.